# Opening an image hyperlink into new window with specified width and height

Tags: html

I wish to open a new window with specified height and width upon clicking an image hyperlink. Trying the following code since long but to no avail. Suggest any addition to it?

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/" target="_blank" scrollbars="YES" 
   resizable="YES"  width="500" height="500">
  <img src="http://logowik.com/uploads/images/456_facebook.jpg" 
    style="width:60px; height:60px; border:none; margin:0; padding:0"/> 
</a>
```

-Chepapu

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is achievable using only HTML. You can use Javascript though:

`window.open("http://someurl.com", "_blank", "width=100, height=100");`

You could simply add a click event to the image hyperlink.

```
    document.getElementById('image-hyperlink').onclick = function() {
window.open("http://facebook.com/", "_blank", "width=500, height=500");
}
```

[window.open()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: You beat me to it. I give you an upvote for the 57 seconds ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In pure HTML that is not possible. The browser may choose to open it in a new tab. You can do it using javascript like this:

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/" onclick="window.open('http://facebook.com/', 
'newwindow', 'width=500,height=500'); return false;">
<img src="http://logowik.com/uploads/images/456_facebook.jpg" 
style="width:60px; height:60px; border:none; margin:0; padding:0"/> 
</a>
```